# C# How to display currency increase decrease?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a currency app which shows Eu and USD rates for Turkey and I want to add little arrows to show if the rates went up or down. However I am new to c#(Xamarin.forms) and this seems a little tricky for me. Can somebody please help :))

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 50, 0, 0);
        else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 20, 0, 0);
        else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
            Padding = new Thickness(30, 20, 0, 0);
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
        doc1.Load("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml");
        XmlElement root = doc1.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("Currency");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {

            var attributeKod = node.Attributes["Kod"].Value;
            if (attributeKod.Equals("USD"))
            {

                var getBanknoteSellingUSD = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteSelling")[0].InnerText;
                var getBanknoteBuyingUSD = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteBuying")[0].InnerText;
                var banknoteSellingUSD = float.Parse(getBanknoteSellingUSD);
                var banknoteBuyingUSD = float.Parse(getBanknoteBuyingUSD);
                labelUsdSELLING.Text = banknoteSellingUSD.ToString("0.00");
                labelUsdBUYING.Text = banknoteBuyingUSD.ToString("0.00");

            }

            var attributeKod1 = node.Attributes["Kod"].Value;
            if (attributeKod1.Equals("EUR"))
            {
                var getBanknoteSellingEU = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteSelling")[0].InnerText;
                var getBanknotesBuyingEU = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteBuying")[0].InnerText;
                var banknoteSellingEU = float.Parse(getBanknoteSellingEU);
                var banknoteBuyingEU = float.Parse(getBanknotesBuyingEU);
                labelEuSELLING.Text = banknoteSellingEU.ToString("0.00");
                labelEuBUYING.Text = banknoteBuyingEU.ToString("0.00");

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if (newRate > previousRate) { ShowUpArrow(); } else if (newRate < previousRate) { ShowDownArrow(); }`. We can't say anything about this without any context or code.

Comment: Here you go :))

Comment: OK, so is your problem that you don't know how to draw the arrows, or that you don't know how to save previous rates so that you can determine if they've gone up or down (since I don't see that information in your XML) or something else?

Comment: Well you just said all my problems.  I don't know how to draw the arrows and saving previous rates...

Comment: Historical rates: if you look at the script at the bottom of this page you can see it constructing an URL for a previous date, e.g. http://tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201806/08062018.xml - although only for weekdays. http://tcmb.gov.tr/wps/wcm/connect/tr/tcmb+tr/main+menu/istatistikler/doviz+kurlari/gosterge+niteligindeki+merkez+bankasi+kurlarii

Answer (score 1):

Create a picturebox in your form and specify path of Up and arrow image as below

```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
                Padding = new Thickness(10, 50, 0, 0);
            else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
                Padding = new Thickness(10, 20, 0, 0);
            else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
                Padding = new Thickness(30, 20, 0, 0);
        }

        Image UpArrowImage
        {
            get { return "Upimage path"; }
        }

        Image DownArrowImage
        {
            get { return "Downimage path"; }
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
            doc1.Load("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml");
            XmlElement root = doc1.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("Currency");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {

                var attributeKod = node.Attributes["Kod"].Value;
                if (attributeKod.Equals("USD"))
                {

                    var getBanknoteSellingUSD = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteSelling")[0].InnerText;
                    var getBanknoteBuyingUSD = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteBuying")[0].InnerText;
                    var banknoteSellingUSD = float.Parse(getBanknoteSellingUSD);
                    var banknoteBuyingUSD = float.Parse(getBanknoteBuyingUSD);

                    var sell = banknoteSellingUSD.ToString("0.00");
                    var buy= banknoteBuyingUSD.ToString("0.00");

                    labelUsdSELLING.Text = sell;
                    labelUsdBUYING.Text = buy;


                    this.pictureBox1.Image = (float.Parse(buy) >float.Parse( sell))?UpArrowImage:DownArrowImage;
                    }

                }

                var attributeKod1 = node.Attributes["Kod"].Value;
                if (attributeKod1.Equals("EUR"))
                {
                    var getBanknoteSellingEU = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteSelling")[0].InnerText;
                    var getBanknotesBuyingEU = node.SelectNodes("BanknoteBuying")[0].InnerText;
                    var banknoteSellingEU = float.Parse(getBanknoteSellingEU);
                    var banknoteBuyingEU = float.Parse(getBanknotesBuyingEU);
                    labelEuSELLING.Text = banknoteSellingEU.ToString("0.00");
                    labelEuBUYING.Text = banknoteBuyingEU.ToString("0.00");

                }

            }

        }
```